# What does the Auto icon do?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-master-duel

When you're playing a Yu-Gi-Oh! Master Duel game, there are three icons in the bottom right (by default)

- On the far right is a battle log which lists every action taken by both players (log icon)
- In the middle is an `i` icon which shows numbers of cards in both decks and extra decks, in each player's hands, in each player's graveyards and in each player's banished zones
- And then, on the left, there's an auto icon which looks like an activated card

What does it do exactly?

Edit: I googled it and found [this](https://gameplay.tips/guides/yu-gi-oh-master-duel-duel-screen-info-guide-duel-field-menu-and-icons.html), it says "Activation Confirmation Button", I guess for the monster, spell and trap cards that can be activated at some point

But why is it "Auto"? What does it do when it's "Auto"?

Comment: I've googled around and found this: https://gameplay.tips/guides/yu-gi-oh-master-duel-duel-screen-info-guide-duel-field-menu-and-icons.html, but I don't understand what it does and where to change it if I want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common setting in Yu-Gi-Oh games.  It controls whether the "do you wish to activate a card?" prompt automatically appears when a player makes an action that you can respond to.

Suppose you have a Quick-Play Spell card face-down on the field, such as [Graceful Dice](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Graceful_Dice).  Any time either player performs an action that you can use to trigger a Chain (i.e. any almost action that isn't a Counter Trap), the game will prompt you as to whether you wish to activate a card, and pause until you select "yes" or "no".

Changing this setting from "Auto" to "Manual" means that the game will *not* automatically prompt you — you will have to keep track of what is going on and press/hold a button to indicate that you wish to activate a card when you wish to do so, which will cause the game to bring up the prompt when it is possible/permitted to do so.  (This is closer to the gameplay experience when using physical cards)